# DB test entries not showing when called via api

Tags: java, quarkus, testcontainers, quarkus-rest-client

I am trying to test my API in a Quarkus APP.
My test setup is I define an object and persist it to the DB with a direct call to the service object. I then call the API and expect to get the object back, but I don't....

My test class setup is;

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestTransaction
@TestHTTPEndpoint(CompanyController.class)
public class CompanyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    CompanyService service;

    @ClassRule
    private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> db = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.3-alpine")
            .withDatabaseName("db")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password");

    @Test
    void test_getCompanyThatExist() {
        service.createCompany(createCompany());

        given()
                .when().get("/1")
                .then().statusCode(200)
                .body("size()", is(1));
    }

    private Company createCompany() {
        Company company = new Company();
        return company;
    }
}
```

Controller endpoint is;

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response getCompany(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    System.out.println("[CompanyController] Getting company with id - " + id);
    Company company = service.getCompany(id);
    System.out.println("[CompanyController] Company got was " + company);
    return Response
            .ok()
            .entity(company)
            .build();
```

Service call is;

```
public Company getCompany(Long id) {
    Company company = repository.findById(id);
    System.out.println("[CompanyService] Got company - " + company);
    return company;
}
```

And the print outs, which really confuses me....
[image: console.logs]

So the object is persisted with an ID of 1, but when I go to get the object with the ID of 1 its null. Any ideas why? As I am completely stumped at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

[QuarkusTest](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/test-framework/junit5/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/junit/QuarkusTest.java) annotation uses JUnit Jupiter's ExtendWith annotation so in this case you should use `@Container` instead of `@ClassRule`, add @Testcontainer at class level and add `org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter` to your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build`

Your test should looks like

```java
@Testcontainers
@QuarkusTest
@TestTransaction
@TestHTTPEndpoint(CompanyController.class)
public class CompanyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    CompanyService service;

    @Container
    private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> db = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.3-alpine")
            .withDatabaseName("db")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password");
}
```

The container can be started/stopped manually too

```java
@QuarkusTest
@TestTransaction
@TestHTTPEndpoint(CompanyController.class)
public class CompanyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    CompanyService service;

    private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> db = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.3-alpine")
            .withDatabaseName("db")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password");

    @BeforeAll
    void beforeAll() {
        db.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    void beforeAll() {
        db.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have done that, but still end up with the same situation. The entity is added to the db on setup but when I query for it, it returns null